# How to find all the lines that match a literal string?

Tags: vimscript, search

How to find all the lines that match exactly a given string, literally?

For literally, I mean that if the string has special characters used in regex, like `*`, `?`, etc., then they shall be consider as-is.

For example, I want the `*` in the string `aa * bb` to be considered  literally and not as "zero or more" quantifier.

**What I tried so far?**

I tried with `search($'\V{my_string}', 'w')`, and it somehow work, but I don't think that is a rigorous solution to the problem, as also someone in the comments also pointed out.

The strings to be searched are automatically generated and therefore I cannot change them but I must take them as they are.

I wish to use builtin functions or methods.

Comment: What about "aa \\* bb"? Is that not working or feasible in your case?

Comment: Not really because the strings to be searched are automatically generated and I cannot modify them but I should take them as-is. I edit my question.

Comment: Found! `$'\V{my_string}'`!!! (in Vim9) Not sure it is the correct way though.

Comment: `\V` will get you close, but then `\*` has meaning. I think you can combine very-no-magic with `escape()` on all the backslashes, though, to make a kind of `regex_quote`.

Comment: In-fact i had the feeling that the solution I found is not very robust. I think I am going to relax my requirement...

Comment: Does [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344903/vim-how-to-search-for-a-hard-coded-string-not-regex) help?